# "PSI and index do not match" on Android Studio - Mac

Tags: macos, android-studio

When I open Android Studio, there displays an error message:

```
PSI and index do not match: PSI and index do not match
```

I can successfully build my project but after building the error message will be displayed once again.

When I open a project there displays:

```
8:08:43 下午 Throwable

       Invalid stub element type in index:

       file: file:///Users/Genius/AndroidSDK/sources/android-21/android/filterfw/geometry/Rectangle.java

       psiElement: PsiTypeParameterList

       requiredClass: interface com.intellij.psi.PsiClass

       actualClass: class com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiTypeParameterListImpl

       virtualFile: size:3091; stamp:10778; modCount:1422357544000; fileType:JAVA; language:JAVA

       psiFile: size:3091; stamp:10778; class:com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaFileImpl; language:JAVA

       stubInfo: created from index; with backReference

       indexing info: indexed at 1422357544000 with size 3091
```

What can I do?
My system is OS X 10.10.1

Answer (score 14):

I believe the correct answer to this is to use the "Invalidate Caches/Restart" option under the file menu. The error message points to a corruption in one of the caches that's rebuilt via this menu command.

Comment: Warning: This deletes shelved changes

Answer (score -1):

I reinstalled Android SDK and the problem is solved.